# SharePoint 2013 - User Profile Service application with active directory import - incremental sync is failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

User profile synchronization service is configured to use SharePoint Active Directory Import in SharePoint 2013 server. Full sync is working fine and only incremental sync is failed with below error.

```
The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob (ID d8b15a26-655b-4c06-8607-50182a301a02) threw an exception.
More information is included below. 
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
```

We have already followed the steps in [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/5bbef3ff-76f1-45f7-b553-73136d504736/user-profile-service-application-user-profile-incremental-synchronization-job-is-failing?forum=sharepointgeneral) technet article and that did not work. What can be the cause and resolution for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to System Settings>Manage services on server> find the User Profile Service ,stop and start it again to compare the result.

If the issue still exists, delete the current connection, create a new connection using AD import to check the result.